# NSInvalidArgumentException while adding NSDictionary to NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I have declared `NSDictionary *dict;` globally and trying to add this `dictionary` into `array` but getting an Error :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

**My Code :**

```
dict = @{@"Testcase" : Testcase, @"TestResult" : TestResult,@"Message": Message};
NSMutableArray * myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[myArray insertObject:dict atIndex:TestcaseId];
```

How to solve this Error ?

Comment: what is `TestcaseId` ..?

Comment: TestcaseId should be less that to your array count ...

Comment: try this [myArray addObject:dict];

Comment: TestcaseId is int which is incrementing to add dict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '* -[__NSArrayM
>   insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

**Problem :** From the above **ErrorMessage**, it is clear that you are trying to add `NULL` value in your `NSDictionary`.

**Explanation :** At the time of inserting *Value* to your `NSDictionary` , note that the *Value* shouldn't be `NULL` and **Non-String**. You are trying to add *Value* of Variable to your *Dictionary* directly. Instead you should try to add like this :

**Answer :**

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Testcase];
```

**Benefits :**

1. It will add *String-Value*.
2. It will add *Empty-Value* when your Value of Variable is `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

```
dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:Testcase:@"Testcase", TestResult: @"TestResult",Message, @"Message", nil];
 NSMutableArray * myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 [myArray insertObject:dict atIndex:TestcaseId];
```

Make sure `TestcaseId` is not more than your `array count`

Answer (score 0):

```
  [myArray addobject:dict];


or

[myArray replaceObjectAtIndex:TestcaseId withObject:dict]
```